# Does Blender provide a web-compatible codec-container combination that allows for transparent backgrounds in videos?

Tags: video

I want to output a video file from my blender animation that (1) has a transparent background, and (2) is supported by the major browsers via a `<video>` element. Ideally, it also won't be a massive file.

Does Blender support such a codec-container combination?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that `container=WebM` and `codec=WEBM/VP9` seems to do the trick ([though Safari doesn't support VP9](https://caniuse.com/#feat=webm) at this moment in time).